# Python: Getting access to instance of my superclass

Tags: python, class, inheritance

i'm trying to get access to a variable of my superclass.

```
class Worker(QRunnable):

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):

        self.threads += 1
        print(self.thrads)
        time.sleep(5)
        self.threads -= 1


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        print("Milthreading with maximum %d threads" % self.threadpool.maxThreadCount())

        self.counter = 0
        self.thrads = 0

    def oh_no(self):
        self.massage = "Pressed"

        worker = Worker()
        self.threadpool.start(worker)
```

Is there some convinced way in python to get access to the MainWindow instances (in my case `self.threads`) from the Worker class when called within the MainWindow namespace and manipulate the `self.threads` from inside?

Comment: Maybe pass `self.threads` as argument to the init or other methods for `Worker` class within `MainWindow`?

Comment: Your question is confusing, You refer to a superclass, which implies an inheritance related question. However unless I am completely misreading this you are not trying to access info from the inheritance structure, You want to access variables in the calling class (Mainwindow) from the called class (Worker). Please edit the subject. @oldwooki already indicated how to handle passing the reference to self.threads. By the way, it appears you have a typo in your MainWindow class, you have ;thrads' but I think you meant 'threads'.